# UpdateLayer Function Resulting in AssertionError

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, symbology

I am providing an alternative to the accepted answer posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264083/applying-symbology-from-layer-to-include-label-properties-feature-scale-range). I pose as new question as the script I use is resulting in error and I've been unable to resolve.

[Esri help documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/updatelayer.htm) states that the `UpdateLayer` function, when altering all of a feature classes symbology properties, may be used as an alternative to the `RemoveLayer` and `AddLayer` functions. The script below is intended to meet the same end as [the question posted above](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264083/applying-symbology-from-layer-to-include-label-properties-feature-scale-range), but it uses this `UpdateLayer` function, which seems like it would be a more elegant solution than using the `RemoveLayer` and `AddLayer` functions.

When I run this script:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import arcpy

# Creates list of MXDs
mxdList = [f for f in listdir(r'C:\MXDs')
             if isfile(join(r'C:\MXDs', f))]

for doc in mxdList:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(r'C:\MXDs', doc))

    # FCs for which there are .lyr files
    fcList = ['FC1', 'FC2', '...']

    # Iterate through dataframes
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]:         
        print df
        workSpaceType = "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE"

        for item in fcList:
            for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, item):
                desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
                geometryType = desc.shapeType

                # Use geometry to match lyr file name
                if geometryType == 'Point':
                    # Access and define the lyr file
                    newLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(r'C:\lyrFiles', item + '_P.lyr'))
                    print 'Layer Object:   ' + str(newLyr)
                    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, newLyr, False)
                    print 'Updated:  ' + str(newLyr)
                    del newLyr

                elif geometryType == 'Polyline':                
                    # Access and define the lyr file
                    newLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(r'C:\lyrFiles', item + '_L.lyr'))
                    print 'Layer Object:   ' + str(newLyr)
                    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, newLyr, False)
                    print 'Updated:  ' + str(newLyr)
                    del newLyr

                elif geometryType == 'Polygon':
                    # Access and define the lyr file
                    newLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join(r'C:\lyrFiles', item + '_A.lyr'))
                    print 'Layer Object:   ' + str(newLyr)
                    arcpy.mapping.UpdateLayer(df, lyr, newLyr, False) 
                    print 'Updated:  ' + str(newLyr)
                    del newLyr


    mxd.saveACopy(r'C:\MXDsUpdated' + doc)
    del mxd
```

it results in error:

```
assert isinstance(data_frame, DataFrame)
    AssertionError
```

for line 58, for the UpdateLayer function for the Polygon geometry, the geometry of the first item in the fcList list for the first MXD that is accessed.

I have ensured I have defined the Layer as described [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/assertion-error-when-attempting-arcpy-mapping-addlayer). Also, inserting the `print df` statement within the `ListDataFrames` `for` loop prints feature class names and not dataframe names. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of my paths were defined incorrectly as Emil Brundage pointed out. I believe the assertion error, however, was due to my use of `mxd` as opposed to `df` in line 22 (`for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, item):`) Upon correcting this line the assertion error no longer appeared.

Thus, this section of the working script now appears like this:

```
for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]: 
    workSpaceType = "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE"    
    for item in fcList:
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df, item):
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will produce a double backslash:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\MXDs\\' + doc)
```

From the Python shell:

```
>>> print r'C:\MXDs\\'
C:\MXDs\\
```

Instead, use:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join (r'C:\MXDs' + doc))
```

This is wrong too:

newLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'C:\lyrFiles/' + item + '_P.lyr')

From the Python shell:

```
>>> item = "FC1"
>>> print r'C:\lyrFiles\/' + item + '_P.lyr'
C:\lyrFiles\/FC1_P.lyr
```

Try:

```
newLyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(os.path.join (r'C:\lyrFiles', item + '_P.lyr'))
```

All your paths need to be rewritten.

Comment: If your paths are bad your code won't work.